# How to modify OpenAPI schema for Mongo record?

Tags: mongodb, openapi, quarkus

By default the OpenAPI schema for a Mongo document contains this for the id.

```
"id": {
  "timestamp": 0,
  "counter": 0,
  "randomValue1": 0,
  "randomValue2": 0,
  "date": "2022-03-10"
}
```

Although its technically correct, that is not what the users want to see, they need to see the single string represented by these object details.  E.g.

```
"id": "d76d6cb6cba140e0a308643c"
```

How can I configure OpenAPI to show this schema this way?

Furthermore how can I tap into the full OpenAPI generated document and make any desired changes prior to it being returned to users and displayed in the Swagger UI?  (We have other customizations we want to make).